# What to use building my application

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, html

I'm building an application for a school project that will allow users to create a route along various locations within a chose category.

The problem is that I have never worked with GPS locations or navigation scripts before and I don't really know how to approach this build. I have been looking at the Google Maps Javascript API V3 for days now but i cant seem to make any progress at all.
So I’m hoping someone could provide me whit some useful information to get me started.

1)

The idea is that the user first makes a selection between a couple of given categories, like say; Art galleries, Architecture and music. after the user has chosen a category, the application will show various locations that are relevant to the chosen category.

Example:
like for instance say the user chooses the category "architecture" he will get the locations of all the great architectural buildings within the given city or village he or she is in.

2)

the next step is that the user can connect the given locations whit one another to create a route between the locations

Example:
The user selects the firs location he wants to visit this will mark the start point of the route. when the next location is selected, it automatically will be connected to the first location and thereby creating a route between the locations.

3)

the final step is that the user will be navigated along the route he created. when the user arrives at a location he or she selected the application provides the user with information about the object that is based on that location. The information is provided in the form of audio speech and text information.

Example:
the user created a route along several outdoor art pieces he wanted to go and see. he starts up the navigation and follows the route. When he arrives at one of the selected locations the application provides him with relevant information about the out door art piece throughout an audio file. That only starts playing when arrives at a selected location.

I’m hoping someone could help me out here because I’m really stuck.

greetings,

Stefan

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad and open-ended to answer. If you can edit it down to something more specific - like "this small piece of code isn't doing what I want it to do" - we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan,

Assuming you covered some of those tags in your class, the best resource I've found for geospatial apps with Gmaps is http://econym.org.uk/gmap/, with some nice tutorials and explanations.

Good luck.